# Error in loading evd package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm having problems loading the evd package in `R v2.12.0`. It worked fine in previous versions.

On the 32bit I get the following message:

```
Error: package 'evd' is not installed for 'arch=i386'
```

and with 64bit:

```
Error: package 'evd' is not installed for 'arch=x64'
```

There are no updates to the package (last release 2008). I've also tried reinstalling the package from the tar.gz but with no joy.

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed and loaded `evd` from CRAN without any problems.  I use R2.13.0 on Windows 7 (64-bit).

To install the package directly from CRAN, use:

```
install.packages("evd")
```

Then to load it:

```
library(evd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with many packages when I upgraded to `2.12.2` from `2.11.0`. I copied the library from the old installation into the new one. I presume to problem is due to a change in the way packages are structured. To solve it I just reinstalled everything from CRAN:

```
install.packages(.packages(all.available=T))
```

Answer (score 1):

`R2.12.0` was changed to make it easier to run R on multiple architectures on the same machine (for example, running 32-bit and 64-bit versions).  This means that each package needs to be installed for a specific architecture.

The fix is to remove your existing packages (back them up first, natch), then reinstall them.